# Magento is showing a blank page when accessing the manage categories page

Tags: magento

When I try to open the manage categories page I only get a blank page. I've tried wiping the cache and deleting some plug-ins which I thought caused the problem but nothing has worked yet. Please help if you know the solution.

Comment: try to enable log and check log file.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by PHP fatal error.
Reason can be tens, but most common is incompatible plugin.

Disable all new plugins, remove cache, clear ./includes/src/ files. Reindex data.
Enable log and check it in the var/log/ folder.